# android equivalent to PHP's function explode()

Tags: php, android, string

Pretty much self-explanatory.

I have a string:

```
8:4,7:2,...
```

I need to get the values from this, the length of the string is not defined, it just has this format:

```
id:quantity,id:quantity,...
```

Comment: whether you want get id or quantity...???

Answer (score 16, accepted):

use string's `split` method to get this:

```
String[] array = "8:4,7:2".split(",");
```

Comment: I was thinking... Shouldn't you just use the split function in java? haha I was right.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to split string to  array use split function

```
String string="8:4,7:2";
String[] array_from_string = string.split(",");
```

if you want to join array elements to string use join function

```
String string_from_array = String.join(",", array_from_string);
```